# ColdFusion float problems

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

Im trying to make my program to show two decimals points but it keeps dropping the zero, so if I have `140.00` it shows as `140.0`, but if I do `140.15` it will show `140.15`. However, for some reason it will always drop the zero. Here is the code I think that needs editing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  <cfinput type="Text" name="HourlyRate" 
       value="0.00" 
       required="Yes" 
       validate="float"              
       message="A Default Hourly Rate is required...."
       class="inputText200" size="8">**
```

or here

```
    <input type="text" name="Rate" 
       <cfif #getHourlyForm.Rate# neq ""> value="#getHourlyForm.Rate#"</cfif> />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that when you're outputting the content into the "value" you're basically rendering HTML.

What that means is that your numeric values are being "converted" into a string representation when CF is generating the HTML.

Check out the [NumberFormat function here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_08.html) which will allow you to tell CF how to output the content rather than it trying to do a "best guess"

```
<tr colspan="2">
        <td class="tdDescription"> Rate Per Hour </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Rate" class="inputText350" <cfif getHourlyForm.Rate neq ""> value="#NumberFormat(getHourlyForm.Rate,"9.99")#"</cfif>/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What Shawn said - #val(numberformat(getHourlyForm.Rate, '000,000.00'))#  ... And you don't need the pound signs inside the "CFIF" statment.